# Monitoring Mirror Maker 2

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to add a template to my monitoring system to monitor Mirror Maker 2.0

From the documentation i know these metrics are supplied in jmx

```
    # MBean: kafka.connect.mirror:type=MirrorSourceConnector,target=. 
   ([-.w]+),topic=([-.w]+),partition=([0-9]+)

    record-count            # number of records replicated source -> target
    record-age-ms           # age of records when they are replicated
    record-age-ms-min
    record-age-ms-max
    record-age-ms-avg
    replication-latecny-ms  # time it takes records to propagate source->target
    replication-latency-ms-min
    replication-latency-ms-max
    replication-latency-ms-avg
    byte-rate               # average number of bytes/sec in replicated records
```

If i wanted to monitor the lag of the replication between clusters, is it supposed to be inferred from record-age-ms? (ie if that age ms continues to grow then the delay continues to grow?)

Thanks